# Expand component to page limit without scroll

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

I have this screen, but the white part I would like to expand it to the bottom limit of the user's screen, but I am not getting it, it has a part in blue as shown in the image.

[Page that is in error](https://i.imgur.com/ZW3ZAcv.jpeg)

Remembering that I would like to make this page responsive regardless of the user's screen size, it has to go to the end

This is my code:

```
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverFillRemaining(
            hasScrollBody: false,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 26.h, bottom: 160.h),
                      child: Container(),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.w),
                      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(8.r),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(8.r),
                        ),
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(height: 32.h),
                          Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text('Thanks for returning',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 16.sp,
                                    color: Colors.blueGrey,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                  )),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 8.h,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                'Enter your password to login into your account: ',
                                softWrap: true,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 22.sp,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 24.h),
                          Form(
                            key: _userCredentialsForm,
                            autovalidateMode:
                                AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                PSInputText(
                                  controller: _passwordController,
                                  inputColor: Colors.blue,
                                  title: 'Password',
                                  hintText: AuthStrings.password,
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                  maxLength: 6,
                                  isObscureText: true,
                                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                                  inputFormatters: [
                                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                                  ],
                                  onChanged: (value) {},
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.h),
                                child: PSPrimaryTextButton(
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                  text: 'Forgot password',
                                  onPressed: () => controller.add(
                                    ForgotPasswordEvent(),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 40.h),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 40.h,
                                child: PSLoginButton(
                                  text: 'Log in',
                                  onPressed: () {},
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.h, top: 32.h),
                            child: FutureBuilder(
                              initialData: '-',
                              future: AppConfig.appVersion,
                              builder: (ctx, appVersion) =>
                                  Text('App Version ${appVersion.data}',
                                      style: TextStyles.fontSize12(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                      )),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

I already tried to use the expand inside column, i also tried to use positioned.fill.

But they all give layout errors, the only solution was to place a sized box to lower the container to the end with its children, but this is not the behavior I would like, since it has a scroll for the user!

Comment: can you post a more relevant screenshot, of what the code actually displays, hard to find what container is the one in question

Comment: @CStark Of course I just updated the photo that is in the description of the problem

Comment: thanks, will take a look at it in a second.

Comment: I'm not sure but whats the purpose of the column inside another column? Also try wrapping the column in an Align(alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, child: ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

You can remove the first column and replace it with Align

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  child:  Column(
     ....
  ),
),
```

Here is a gist of the change
https://dartpad.dev/?id=66d3ec6382c544939750609d558d63f8

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to put the Login button to bottom of the page. You can increase the padding of forgot password button according to the screen height.

```
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 450,),
  child: PSPrimaryTextButton(
    fontSize: 14,
    text: 'Forgot password',
    onPressed: () => controller.add(
      ForgotPasswordEvent(),
    ),
  ),
),
```

In this code block I add padding with subtracting 450 from height of device.

Expanded won't work because we have unlimited height. It can't help us.